# Graphics.drawString in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to draw string in multiple lines and and I want to know how many lines given string will take.
I am using following method.

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(msg.msgBody, e.Font, New SolidBrush(Color.Black), RectangleF.op_Implicit(newRect))
```

I know how much size the given string will take by calculating

```
Dim siz As SizeF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(msg.msgBody, ListBox1.Font, e.ItemWidth)
```

Is there any way by passing rectangle we can calculate number of lines given string will take?

Thanks

Comment: Are you drawing the string directly onto the form during the Paint event?

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at the [overloads for the `Graphics.MeasureString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx) reveals one that returns the number of text lines in the string as a `ByRef` parameter:

```
Public Function MeasureString ( _
    text As String, _
    font As Font, _
    layoutArea As SizeF, _
    stringFormat As StringFormat, _
    <OutAttribute> ByRef charactersFitted As Integer, _
    <OutAttribute> ByRef linesFilled As Integer _
) As SizeF
```

The direct link to the documentation for that particular overload can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/957webty.aspx), complete with working sample code.